# Difference between open and closed center toroid transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, power-electronics, toroid

I just want to know, what is the difference between open center and closed center toroidal transformer. Open center meaning the toroid has a metal rod in the middle while the open center doesn't have anything in the middle.

Open: https://my.element14.com/vigortronix/vtx-146-050-215/50va-toroidal-transformer-2x15v/dp/2817652

Closed: https://my.element14.com/multicomp/mcta500-35/transformer-toroidal-2-x-35v-500va/dp/9532951

Comment: Can you post a link/picture of such toroid transformer?

Comment: updated with links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between open center and closed center toroidal transformer?

There is almost no difference.  Just one is ready for mounting.

Large toroidal transformers are usually bolted this way simply because it is convenient.  Smaller ones may be glued into a base, either horizontally or vertically, with nothing in the center.

Consider that the toroid itself is the "conductor" of magnetism. It has a high magnetic permeability, so the vast majority of magnetic flux is contained inside that.

Whether a rod is placed in the center of the toroid makes little difference to the operation *inside* the toroid.  This rod is also at a right angle (perpendicular) to the flux inside the toroid (circular), so it has even less of an effect.  So the rod does not act as a "shorted turn" or anything and is largely "invisible" to the toroid.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't act as a shorted turn? If you're careless with how you mount it, it absolutely can.

Answer (score 0):

What you call it closed is a mounting accessory. You drill the plate where you want to fix the transformer and then you bolt the transformer, the metal cap is a retainer.

[image]
[image]

Comment: So basically, there is not technical difference between these two?

Comment: @RogerDsuza Those linked are big different: power, voltage, size,...But if you think about technology, it's the same. The one "closed" it may not be delivered with a mounting accessory, it's just a photo showing it. Usually, the mounting kit , you have to buy separately, so  what you probably get are the same looking transformers.